# connect remotehost through localhost using websockets

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I'm using [this](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) web socket hosted by google

```
var host = "ws://localhost:12345/websocket/server.php";
try{
  socket = new WebSocket(host);
  log('WebSocket - status '+socket.readyState);
  socket.onopen    = function(msg){ log("Welcome - status "+this.readyState); };
  socket.onmessage = function(msg){ log("Received: "+msg.data); };
  socket.onclose   = function(msg){ log("Disconnected - status "+this.readyState); };
}
catch(ex){ log(ex); }
```

is this work with remotehost ?

```
var host = "ws://example.com:12345/websocket/server.php";
```

**I want to POST changes using CURL using websockets.**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://xxxx.com/ccc.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "esoftcareers.crt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
http_build_query(array('PHPSESSID' => $id ,'query' => $resultQuery,'operator' => $operator,'database' => DATABASE)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: In principle it should, but could depend on a number of factors (is that port open and available on the remote machine? etc.)

Comment: Are you saying you want to connect two web servers using websockets? Websockets is a client server protocol. The client libraries are built into Google Chrome. It looks like you have found the reference documentation here ( http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/ ) for building the server side. If you want to build a client library in PHP that will be a much larger task.

Comment: Exists some error? The curl is enable? Simple but good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** of all let start my answer from this:

> **I want to POST changes using CURL using websockets.**

WebSocket is [protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) first of all for browser-based(not server to server) applications that need two-way communication with servers. You want to use use `http/https protocols` in curl(because `post` is the method of HTTP protocol) which are the layer over TCP. The WebSocket is also [layered](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) over TCP. So you want to use one TCP layer by another. Now you can't to do it, because php curl don't [support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php) websocket protocol. And I think it still immutable in the future.

Also `post` is method of HTTP protocol which has body and has one response. WebSocket is protocol without body and it use a sequence of frames. So there is no anything like `post`  method in websocket protocol and this is his feature.

And you can't send something server and forgot about it in websocket, because socket means communicate. You must communicate with server when using websocket. In HTTP via AJAX you can send something to server and use async callbacks to process the response. In websocket if you close it you will lose all your data in response.

You can emulate websocket by curl using long-pulling requests. But it's still HTTP protocol, not websocket. So now curl can't use websocket  protocol.

**The second**. About websocket protocol origin(via cross domain). Yes, websocket can use cross domain, because it [use](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) origin-based security model. So if you try to open connection with web server by WebSocket from domain which is absent in `Origin` request header server will return [appropriate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.3) HTTP error. Usually 403 HTTP error by default. In other case all must be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Server and client both should be aware of the `websocket` implementation and the first handshake should conclude that they both do know.  by the first next line from the `ws:` response from the server ... `"Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n"`. If there is no such response from server, the websocket expecting client should understand that there is no support for websocket in the currently contacting server and fallback to normal communication.

**ADDED NOTE :**
Plain curl things could not benefit from this protocol unless you have an advance curl command which is updated with this protocol implementation. Please find [this](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2010-04/0386.html) and [this](http://www.thenerdary.net/post/24889968081/debugging-websockets-with-curl).

Comment: Whoever voted negative to this answer, I ask them to prove that this answer is wrong. (Websocket is a new protocol and it should be implemented to realize that. Nothing is a miracle that browsers implement even the foreseen protocols which will be developed in the future)